# Authentication, sharedpreference flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

i created a login page but have a problem when i firt start on my phone.
i use sharedpreference to save "isLoggedIn" (true or false), if is true they are logged if is false they aren t logged.

So when i start first time, isloggedIn start with true, but i want he start with false for get register page.

I don t kwon if is possible change start value of "isLoggedIn", or have outer solution for this case

this is the code i use to see what page should it start.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    verificarToken().then((value) {
      if (value == 'true') {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginSuccess()));
      } else {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Login()));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text('Loading...')),
    );
  }
}

Future<String> verificarToken() async {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreference = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  if (sharedPreference.getBool('isLoggedIn') != false) {
    return 'true';
  } else {
    return 'false';
  }
```

After first run this works well, the problem is only at the beginning

Comment: sharedpref will save the value in your device.  to test it you have to clear data first. or uninstall the app

Comment: also when logout, make sure you save islogin= false

Comment: is there any way to clear the date before making the apk?
or to know what value isLoggenIn has before creating the apk

Comment: because the problem is only the first time the login page should appear. It's working when I log out or log in and go back to the app

Comment: when first time you install the apk, `isLogin` = null.

Comment: once you successfully login, the value of `isLogin` = true.

Comment: ok so when I install the app for the first time the value of the islogin that comes is null?

Comment: thanks for the help, it actually returns a null so I just had to change the "if (sharedPreference.getBool('isLoggedIn') != false)" to "if (sharedPreference.getBool('isLoggedIn') == true)"

Comment: yes, thats correct. 
glad to help.